# Android smb: jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to negotiate

Tags: android, exception, smb

I am trying to develop a android application using smb. I am trying to list the network places available in the LAN. I am using following piece of code to do so:

```
            SmbFile[] domains;
            domains = (new SmbFile("smb://")).listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < domains.length; i++) {
                SmbFile[] servers;
                try {
                    servers = domains[i].listFiles();
                } catch (SmbException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < servers.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println("Network places....  " +servers[j].getName());
                }
            }

        } catch (SmbException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am getting the list of networks but randomly I get following exception:

```
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to negotiate
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    jcifs.smb.SmbException: Timeout trying to open socket
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.start(SmbTransport.java:315)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate0(SmbTransport.java:865)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate(SmbTransport.java:941)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:119)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:827)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:797)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doNetEnum(SmbFile.java:1634)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.listFiles(SmbFile.java:1604)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.listFiles(SmbFile.java:1514)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at com.lnt.ts.explorer.FileExplorerActivity$ConnectToServer.doInBackground(FileExplorerActivity.java:108)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at com.lnt.ts.explorer.FileExplorerActivity$ConnectToServer.doInBackground(FileExplorerActivity.java:1)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate(SmbTransport.java:947)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:119)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:827)
08-21 12:12:22.336: W/System.err(10141):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:797)
08-21 12:12:22.341: W/System.err(10141):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doNetEnum(SmbFile.java:1634)
08-21 12:12:22.341: W/System.err(10141):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.listFiles(SmbFile.java:1604)
08-21 12:12:22.341: W/System.err(10141):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.listFiles(SmbFile.java:1514)
08-21 12:12:22.341: W/System.err(10141):    at com.lnt.ts.explorer.FileExplorerActivity$ConnectToServer.doInBackground(FileExplorerActivity.java:108)
08-21 12:12:22.341: W/System.err(10141):    at com.lnt.ts.explorer.FileExplorerActivity$ConnectToServer.doInBackground(FileExplorerActivity.java:1)
08-21 12:12:22.341: W/System.err(10141):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-21 12:12:22.341: W/System.err(10141):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-21 12:12:22.341: W/System.err(10141):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-21 12:12:22.341: W/System.err(10141):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-21 12:12:22.341: W/System.err(10141):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-21 12:12:22.341: W/System.err(10141):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I am not able to figure out how to resolve this exception(Googled a lot with no luck). Please suggest how can I resolve this exception. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are using latest jar which is jcifs-1.3.15.jar as of now and not the lower versions like jcifs-1.1.11.jar etc